# QSignalManager - Cant connect multiple signals to one slot

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I have 4 QLineEdits and 4 QPushButtons. If I click onto a QPushButton, I want to set some text inside the corresponding QLineEdit.
I want to use a QSignalMapper to distinguish between each QButton and it's corresponding QLineEdit, so if Button1 is clicked, I want to set the text in Edit1.

In the constructor of my maindwindow I do the following:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    signalMapper = new QSignalMapper(this);

    // set mapping and pass QLineEdit as parameter    
    signalMapper->setMapping(ui->btn1,  ui->edit1);
    signalMapper->setMapping(ui->btn2,  ui->edit2);
    signalMapper->setMapping(ui->btn3,  ui->edit3);
    signalMapper->setMapping(ui->btn4,  ui->edit4);

    // now connect the clicked()-signal to the mapping
    connect(ui->btn1, &QPushButton::clicked, signalMapper, &QSignalMapper::map);
    connect(ui->btn2, &QPushButton::clicked, signalMapper, &QSignalMapper::map);
    connect(ui->btn3, &QPushButton::clicked, signalMapper, &QSignalMapper::map);
    connect(ui->btn4, &QPushButton::clicked, signalMapper, &QSignalMapper::map);

    // connect signalMapper to my my function
    connect(signalMapper, SIGNAL(mapped(QObject*)), this, SLOT(setFileName(QObject*)));
}
```

For testing purposes, I want to display the text of the edit that I "linked" to each button with this slot:

```
void MainWindow::setFileName(QObject* target)
{
    QLineEdit* edit = qobject_cast<QLineEdit*>(target);
    QMessageBox msgBox;
    msgBox.setText(edit->text());
    msgBox.exec();
}
```

But this does not even compile and I don't understand the problem:
http://pastebin.com/v5sD06yJ

Could somebody explain to me what is wrong with my code?
This is my project : https://copy.com/2kDf8Jr0v1if

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `..\Menue_Editor\mainwindow.cpp:28:89: error: no matching function for call to 'MainWindow::connect(QPushButton*&, void (QAbstractButton::*)(bool), QSignalMapper*&, <unresolved overloaded function type>)'` looks like an ambiguity in which function you are referring to

Comment: try `&QAbstractButton::clicked` instead `&QPushButton::clicked`.

Comment: hmm yeah I also think that, but I cant figure out what i am doing wrong...

Comment: @MarekR : Changing in to AbstractButton results in the same error

Comment: It looks lie an ambiguity between `QSignalMapper::map()` and `QSignalMapper::map(QObject * sender)` isn't it?

Comment: @skylla, is new connection syntax significant for you? If not you can rewrite with old syntax and it will work.

Comment: If i rewrite it to old Syntax I can compile it, but nothing happens, the button click does not trigger anyything...

Answer (score 3):

Your compilation error can be resolved under the new connect() syntax with a cast.  So change:

```
connect(
    ui->targetfile_btn, &QPushButton::clicked,
    signalMapper, &QSignalMapper::map
);
connect(
    ui->sourcefile_btn, &QPushButton::clicked,
    signalMapper, &QSignalMapper::map
);
connect(
    ui->multilizer4_btn, &QPushButton::clicked,
    signalMapper, &QSignalMapper::map
);
connect(
    ui->multilizer6_btn, &QPushButton::clicked,
    signalMapper, &QSignalMapper::map
);
```

To:

```
connect(
    ui->targetfile_btn, &QPushButton::clicked,
    signalMapper, static_cast<void (QSignalMapper::*)()>(&QSignalMapper::map)
);
connect(
    ui->sourcefile_btn, &QPushButton::clicked,
    signalMapper, static_cast<void (QSignalMapper::*)()>(&QSignalMapper::map)
);
connect(
    ui->multilizer4_btn, &QPushButton::clicked,
    signalMapper, static_cast<void (QSignalMapper::*)()>(&QSignalMapper::map)
);
connect(
    ui->multilizer6_btn, &QPushButton::clicked,
    signalMapper, static_cast<void (QSignalMapper::*)()>(&QSignalMapper::map)
);
```

It may be a little clunkier-looking than the SIGNAL() and SLOT() macros, but worth it for checking properly compatible slots at compile-time vs. run-time.

Were it me, I'd turn on C++11 (for sure) and write something like `auto mapSignal = static_cast<void (QSignalMapper::*)()>(&QSignalMapper::map);` and then use mapSignal.  But there are other approaches.

Comment: Thank you for another compiling solution. But also if I change my code with your adaptations, nothing happens if I click my buttons, I dont even enter the setFileName() method...

Comment: @skylla I rolled back your edits to the question to the original.  It's not how things work on StackOverflow to ask a question, get an answer...and then update your question incorporating that answer so that prior answers do not make sense anymore.  Ask new questions when the question is substantially different.  "Why does my code not compile" is not the same as "why doesn't this compiling code do what I want"; and may in fact even be the sort of question completely different audiences would have expertise in answering.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, I'm sry. Should I open another question and roll back my changes here?

Comment: @skylla I already did that.  But yes, a new question is in order.  I'll raise the point of also keeping in mind some of the good principles of minimal questions.  For example, if you can demonstrate the problem with two line edits and connect calls (or even one) instead of four...that's more focused.

Answer (score 2):

I would do the same in the following way:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    // Establish connections.
    connect(ui->btn1, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(setFileName()));
    connect(ui->btn2, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(setFileName()));
    connect(ui->btn3, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(setFileName()));
    connect(ui->btn4, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(setFileName()));
}
```

and

```
void MainWindow::setFileName()
{
    QObject *btn = sender();
    if (btn == ui->btn1) {
        ui->edit1->setText("Text1);
    } else if (btn == ui->btn2) {
        ui->edit2->setText("Text2);
    } else if (btn == ui->btn3)
    [..]
}
```

Comment: Hi, thankyou for the answer, but I wanted to try out the signalMapper with passing an QObject to solve this.

Comment: put those buttons in a buttongroup, use their id as key to map lineedit and prevent `if else` mess